# Phrasal verbs meaning stop being consistent in doing something?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I would like to know some commonly-used phrasal verbs referring to the action of stop being consistent in doing something. A phrasal verb that sounds natural and can be used in the following context.

*e.g. I  started to work out four times a week last spring, I was doing great,but I (**gradually stopped doing so**) lately.*

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, "I've [***slackened off***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slack%20off) lately." From Merriam-Webster:

> Definition of slack off
>
> 1 : to do something with less effort or energy than before
>  *I was
>   exercising regularly last summer, but I've been slacking off recently.*

Answer (score 0):

[**Give up**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/give-up)

> to stop doing something that you do regularly

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **tail off**.

From [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tail-off)]:

> *tail off* — phrasal verb with tail verb: to reduce in amount or become
>   lower in level

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tail%20off) adds the 'gradually', probably connected with the tapering of a tail, though doesn't give a wide enough definition:

> *tail off* phrasal verb: to become smaller or quieter in a gradual way

ditto for [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tail+off):

> *tail off*: to dwindle, diminish, or fade away.
>
> *His campaign started really strong, but public support for the candidate tailed off following a series of scandals.*

But they *do* include an 'agent [here non-sentient] reduces [here perceived] output' example:

> *The lights on the car began tailing off into the blackness of the night, leaving me alone in the empty field.*

'Tail off' is often used to describe speech, even as a quote verb. But none of the dictionaries I've checked in mention the running sense, but it is quite common, especially in horse-racing. Here is one example [[LivesRunning](https://livesrunning.wordpress.com/tag/800m/)], involving a human agent:

> He attacked the field, running the first lap in 58 seconds (as fast,
>   by comparison, as the women’s Olympic final), and, if he tailed off
>   afterwards, still he just about held on to finish in around 2 minutes
>   15.

It's not much of a further metaphorical stretch to apply it to gradually falling away from other exercise (and then any other practice). I've only been able to find an [anecdotal example from mumsnet](https://www.mumsnet.com/Talk/general_health/1707714-Anyone-else-need-motivation-to-do-pelvic-floor-exercises) on the internet:

> I've been to the physio, and started off doing my exercises
>   religiously. Have tailed off somewhat now.

Answer (score 0):

**Faltered**

Faltered means to ‘fail in walking’ or lose your step, it is traditionally also used to describe ‘sinners who have lost their path’ or gone wrong.

To lose strength or purpose, to begin to fail or stop.

- I started to work out four times a week last spring, I was doing great, but I faltered lately.
- I was learning the violin but then I faltered.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/falter

Answer (score -1):

There are so many:

- Stay away from
- Get out of
- Duck out of/Wriggle out of/ flinch from/ abstain from and refrain from.

Any one will do. But if you are still in the process, write

- Cut down
- Bring down
- Shave off
- Whittle away.

Comment: **give up** may be suitable.